# How to delete a created firestore database.?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a firestore database in firebase. Now I no longer need that,I couldn't found any option to delete it.Is there any option ?

Comment: What do you mean through "entire database to be deleted"?

Comment: Just like a fresh firebase project. (With Create database option)

Comment: Then delete the project and create a new one.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's no way option to delete Firestore in Firebase UI, neither in Google Cloud. You can remove the whole project or let it be. You won't be billed for it if you don't use it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the CLI to **delete the entire database**:

`firebase firestore:delete --all-collections`

It will list all the collections in your Firestore and ask you for confirmation if you really want to drop everything.

Comment: Thanks for this - it deletes the content of the database, not removes the database from the google cloud nor deletes the firebase project. And this command I needed! (as importing databases via google cloud is an upsert).

Answer (score 4):

To delete a DB in Firestore, you can also use `gcloud`. For the default DB you have to use this command: `gcloud alpha firestore databases delete --database='(default)'`

Comment: @habeeb-rahman this is definitely the answer, we gotta use gcloud cli to delete the database in our firebase project.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete The Collection which will delete all the documents and fields inside it.

It is Given in Firebase Console.

[image]

Comment: i want the entire database to be deleted not the collection or its data

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much data is in the DB you could delete it one top-level collection at a time using the firebase CLI command:

```
firebase firestore:delete "COLLECTION_NAME" --recursive
```

Where COLLECTION_NAME is the name of a collection at the top level of your DB. This command can only delete a few hundred or thousand docs in a few seconds before it starts failing and you need to run it again. I just keep running it until all the docs and collections in my top level collection are deleted.

Answer (score -3):

Click on Project Overview.

[image]

Now click on the device icon *(in this example the Android icon)*.

[image]

Click on the cogwheel icon.

[image]

Then at the bottom of the page click on delete project, check all the options and delete your project.

[image]

Comment: This will delete the entire project.